# Можно ли сравнивать итераторы одного типа из разных контейнеров?

Tags: c++

К примеру у нас есть:

```
std::list<int> a;
std::list<int> b;

auto iter0 = a.begin();
auto iter1 = b.begin();

if(iter0 != iter1) {
   ...
}
```

Понятно, что итераторы никогда не будут равны для разных контейнеров, но мне интересно, что говорит по этому стандард? Это неопределенное поведение, или нет?

Comment: Сам по себе не разыменованный итератор указывает на участок памяти, сравнивать их не имеет никакого смысла грубо говоря, но если говорить о данных, на который указывает этот итератор, то это рабочий вариант. Как минимум вы сможете сравнить два числа.

Comment: @raviga меня интересует этот вопрос именно с позиции стандарта, т к gcc и clang допускают такое сравнение, но не visual studio (debug)

Comment: @raviga: Никакого "указывает на участок памяти" для итераторов не постулируется. Итератор - не указатель.

Comment: @AnT http://eel.is/c++draft/iterator.requirements Iterators are a generalization of pointers that allow a C++ program to work with different data structures (for example, containers and ranges) in a uniform manner. Since iterators are an abstraction of pointers, their semantics are a generalization of most of the semantics of pointers in C++

Comment: @raviga: Это замечательно, но ключевые термины здесь - именно *generalization* и *abstraction*. Итераторы предоставляют вам доступ к знечени. через оператор `*`. А вот что за всем эти скрывается: "участок памяти" или что-то иное - это уже выходит за раки этой *abstraction*.

Comment: @AnT это да, понимаю

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Да, это неопределенное поведение. Сравнение итераторов из разных контейнеров не допускается. Оператор `==` требует, чтобы оба итератора итерировали по одной и той же последовательности

[[iterator.concept.forward]p2](http://eel.is/c++draft/iterator.concept.forward#2)

---

Что интересно, стандарт C++14 разрешил сравнение между собой однотипных value-инициализированных итераторов

```
std::vector<int>::iterator a{}, b{};
assert(a == b);
```

но сравнение таких итераторов с другими "нормальными" итераторами по-прежнему не допускается.